# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists in Spring Data Neo4j when using imported data

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Trying to retrieve nodes in SDN, imported using the [Neo4j CSV Batch Importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import), gives the java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one with starting  with _)
```

This is after having added a new label through a cypher query:

```
match (n:Movie) set n:_Movie;
```

Inspecting nodes created through SDN shows they have the same labels. The result when running

```
match (n) where id(n)={nodeId} return labels(n) as labels;
```

as found in [LabelBasedStrategyCypher.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/1bd9c20787c2589b84cc1f3498675ea34d5c13e3/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/typerepresentation/LabelBasedStrategyCypherHelper.java) is the same for both:

```
["Movie","_Movie"]
```

Saving and retrieving nodes thorugh SDN works without any issues. I must be missing something as I got the impression that setting the [appropiate labels](http://neo4j.com/blog/spring-data-neo4j-progress-update-sdn-3-neo4j-2) should be enough.

I'm running SDN 3.0.2.RELEASE and neo4j 2.0.3 on arch linux x64 with Oracle Java 1.8.0_05

Edit: My CSV file looks like this. The appId is only used to assure the node is the same that we have stored earlier, as [the internal nodeId is Garbage collected](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html) and new nodes could get old nodeIds after the old ones are deleted. The nodeId is used for actual lookups and for connecting relationships and so on.

```
appId:int   l:label title:string:movies year:int
1   Movie   Dinosaur Planet 2003
2   Movie   Isle of Man TT 2004 Review  2004
```

Edit2:

I have made more tests, checking the source of LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy to see what is going wrong. Running the readAliasFrom() method that the Exception is thrown from does not return any errors:

```
String query = "start n=node({id}) return n";
Node node = null;
for(Node n : neo4jTemplate.query(query,params).to(Node.class)){
    node = n;
}

// when running the readAliasFrom method manually the label is returned correctly
LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy strategy = new 
        LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy(neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabase());
System.out.println("strategy returns:  " +(String)strategy.readAliasFrom(node));

// trying to convert the node to a movie object, however throws the Illegal State Exception
Movie movie = null;
movie = neo4jTemplate.convert(node,Movie.class);
```

So, the _Movie label exists, running the readAliasFrom() method manually doesn't throw Exceptions but trying to convert the node into a Movie does. Nodes created from SDN do not have these issues, even if they look identical to me.

Comment: Can you post a bit of your CSV file?

Comment: I have updated the question with some lines from the CSV file.